# What scripts or programs can I use to speed up the process of user management in linux?

Tags: linux

So in Linux, I usually try to manage my users by editing the /etc/passwd file. Though this can be a large file since daemons and other processes make accounts in this file. In most case scenarios is given a list of users that are authorized to use a system. If I were to write a script that can help speed up this process what would be the best way to make it? What would the framework of this look like? Other than creating a custom script is there a program out there that does this task?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! /etc/passwd is a file you shouldn't edit. Do as @ivanivan said.

Answer (score 1):

What could you be doing that needs editing the `/etc/passwd` file that can't be done via `adduser`, `useradd`, `usermod` or `deluser` ?  And yes, there are equivalents to those to manage groups as well.

Don't reinvent the wheel.  The frameworks and programs have been there for over 30 years.